# Can a [mod] (or someone else) make this tag a synonym of [modulo]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

From the [mod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod) excerpt:

> For questions related with the *mod operation*, that can arise in Cryptography, Number Theory, Hashing, etc..

This is literally the same thing as [modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulo).

I propose [mod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod) be made a synonym of [modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulo).

Comment: This needs a cleanup...24 of the most recent 50 questions are not about that topic, but mostly about either game mods (usually Minecraft) or about modules.  The ratio is far worse in the more recent ones, too.

Comment: @RyanM If "mod" gets hidden underneath "modulo" as per the synonym request, then anyone posting a question will only get a tag suggestion "modulo", so I think that would solve the problem.

Comment: @Lundin but synonymizing now would merge those non [[tag:modulo]] tags into it which is why RyanM is right that there should be a cleanup before making it a synonym. Don't know how your comment solves that problem for the existing wrongly tagged questions.

Comment: @cafce25 Existing posts are already incorrectly tagged and making tags synonyms won't fix that indeed. It's two separate problems: preventing mis-tagging in the future and cleaning up the present mess.

Comment: There are only a few hundred questions, and there are multiple things people might expect the tag to mean (as evidenced by the mis-tags). I think we should be talking about burnination rather than synonymization. If we cleanup and synonymize, I predict a future in which people are confused as to why questions about modding Minecraft are tagged `modulo`. If anything, *that* tag should be synonymized to `modular-arithmetic` (which is less used, but clearer while also avoiding premature specialization).

Comment: The questions have been substantially cleaned up now. The most recent 100 questions now appear to be all about modulo operations. This query probably contains further questions that need cleanup: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmod%5D+htaccess+is%3Aq and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmod%5D+rewrite+is%3Aq

Comment: In addition to the game/ software "mod" usages, also cleaned up a bunch of [apache] and [.htaccess] questions which used it mostly to refer to [mod-rewrite] and related [apache-modules]. Agree with TylerH though, things seem much cleaner now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag appears to be pretty much entirely about the intended topic now. Thank you to the folks who helped clean this up.

I cleaned up a couple remaining items about modules (and one about [WooCommerce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WooCommerce) mods), including specifically a few about Apache mod_* things.  I also found a few module-related questions in the [modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulo) tag and retagged those to [module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/module).

I've merged [mod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod) into [modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulo) <del>and created a synonym, since many people refer to the operation as simply "mod".  If that ends up being a problem, we can remove the synonym</del>.  The synonym was removed, because it was almost immediately a problem.

```
updating post history, 379 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 321 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 303 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'mod': [mod] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 1953
tag remapping of [modulo] and [mod] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
161 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
21 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym mod -> modulo was approved!
```

Comment: The question version https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77292601/1 shows the immediate problem with the [tag:mod] synonym for [tag:module]. It was fixed by the OP later on, but it shouldn't happen in the first place. The synonym [tag:mod] shouldn't exists but instead should be banned/locked. The abbreviation "mod" is equally used for other common topics like game mods and mod-rewrite. On that note, maybe we should create a new tag "game-mod", which immediately catches all these game mod related questions.

Comment: @Progman yikes, already?  That didn't take long... Okay, synonym gone.  I figured that it would be not much worse, because there was already some misuse of "modulo" for modules, but...actually they are probably typing "mod" and seeing a word that looks a lot like "module", which is making it worse.

Comment: @RyanM the tag suggestion engine hasn't changed much then... it'd be interesting to see what was suggested by the system on the timeline